# All balanced parentheses for a given N

Tags: algorithm, strings, haskell, balanced-delimiters

> Write a function (in Haskell) which makes a list of strings
>   representing all of the ways you can balance N pairs of parentheses:
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> balancedParens 0
> [""]
> balancedParens 1
> ["()"]
> balancedParens 2
> ["()()","(())"]
> balancedParens 3
> ["()()()","(())()","()(())","(()())","((()))"]
> ```

My code produces the right answer but is very slow.

I would appreciate any help on how to speed it up (I have little Haskell experience, so the main struggle for me was implementing the proper algorithm).

```
module Balanced.Parens where

import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

mutateBP :: String -> [String]
mutateBP "()" = ["(())", "()()"]
mutateBP  xs  = [xs ++ "()", "()" ++ xs, "(" ++ xs ++ ")"]

continuousSubSeqs :: String -> [String]
continuousSubSeqs = filter (not . null) . concatMap inits . tails

indicesOfSubStr :: String -> String -> [Int]
indicesOfSubStr []  _   = []
indicesOfSubStr sub str = filter (\i -> sub `isPrefixOf` drop i str) $ head sub `elemIndices` str

splitBP :: String -> String -> [[String]]
splitBP s xs = chunksOf 2 (concat (map (\i -> [take (i + 1) xs, drop (i + 1) xs]) (indicesOfSubStr s xs)))

get1st :: (a,b,c) -> a
get1st (a,_,_) = a

get2st :: (a,b,c) -> b
get2st (_,b,_) = b

get3st :: (a,b,c) -> c
get3st (_,_,c) = c

zipWithNums' :: String -> [(Char, Int, Int)]
zipWithNums' xs = zip3 xs (parensNum xs) [0..]

findMatch "" = (0, "", "", 0)
findMatch xs = (length xs, group, tail', matchIdx)
  where zipWithNums = zip3 xs (parensNum xs) [0..]
        matchNum = 1 + (get2st $ head zipWithNums)
        matchPar = if '(' == (get1st . head) zipWithNums then ')' else '('
        matchAndTail = dropWhile (\x -> (get1st x /= matchPar) || (get2st x /= matchNum) ) (tail zipWithNums)
        matchIdx = if 0 == length matchAndTail then 0 else (get3st $ head matchAndTail) + 1
        group = take matchIdx xs
        tail' = drop matchIdx xs

groups xs = nub $ filter (\x -> (length $ get2st x) /= 0) [(take (xs_l - l) xs, g, t) | (l, g, t, idx) <- map findMatch (tails xs)]
  where xs_l = length xs

parensNum :: String -> [Int]
parensNum xs = scanl (\acc x -> if '(' == x then acc + 1 else acc - 1) 1 xs

isValidBP :: String -> Bool
isValidBP "" = True
isValidBP xs = (length valid_parens_num) - 1 == length xs
  where parens_num = parensNum xs
        valid_parens_num = takeWhile (>0) parens_num

balancedParens :: Int -> [String]
balancedParens 0 = [""]
balancedParens 1 = ["()"]
balancedParens n = nub $ concat $ map (\x -> [p ++ z ++ s| p <- [get1st x], z <- mutateBP $ get2st x, s <- [get3st x]]) gr
  where gr = concat $ map groups (balancedParens (n - 1))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code can be sped up, and it can also be simplified. For `n > 0`, there is a unique way to write a balanced string as `(a)b` where `a` and `b` are balanced strings.

`a` and `b` must have `n-1` pairs of parentheses, total. This leads us to the following solution:

```
balancedParens 0 = [""]
balancedParens n = ["(" ++ a ++ ")" ++ b | i <- [0 .. n - 1], a <- balancedParens i, b <- balancedParens (n - i - 1)]
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! I need to sleep on it to fully understand the idea. I feel really stupid right now :-)